# jQuery conflict on nested_form gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So, I think this is maybe a problem with me being a JS newb and also a recent Rails upgrade. I'm trying to use Ryan Bates' nested_form gem to create a complex dynamic nested form. The page loads ok and looks fine, but when I click the "add" and "remove" links, nothing happens. Hovering over the links gives me javascript:void(0). Using the JavaScript observer in Chrome, I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'observe'
```

Some googling tells me that this means I'm having a conflict with Prototype, but I am not using Prototype (or anything but jQuery) anywhere in my application.

Here's my guess at the relevant info. Please tell me if I've left anything out.

I'm using rails 3.2.4 rc 1 and ruby 1.9.3, on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

My gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.github.com'
gem 'rails', '3.2.4.rc1'

gem 'mysql'

gem 'execjs'

gem 'therubyracer'

gem 'nested_has_many_through'
gem 'validates_date_time'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
gem 'formtastic', :git => 'git://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic.git', :branch => '2.1-stable'
gem "nested_form", :git => 'git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'
```

My tree from application.js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require_tree .
```

Contents of assets/javascripts:

```
application.js
nested_form.js
rails.js
```

There isn't anything in public/javascripts.

Lastly, here's what the console puts out during page load (it's for the edit page of a Play, which has_many Acts--I'm trying to use nested_form to add and remove Acts)

```
[2012-07-15 08:10:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=23455 port=3000


Started GET "/acts/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-15 08:10:32 -0400
Processing by ActsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Act Load (3.5ms)  SELECT `acts`.* FROM `acts` WHERE `acts`.`id` = ? ORDER BY act_number LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Play Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `plays`.* FROM `plays` WHERE `plays`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Scene Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `scenes`.* FROM `scenes` WHERE `scenes`.`act_id` = 1 ORDER BY scene_number
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered acts/_scene_fields.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered acts/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (317.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 558ms (Views: 407.1ms | ActiveRecord: 12.7ms)
[2012-07-15 08:10:33] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-15 08:10:33 -0400
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (30ms)
[2012-07-15 08:10:33] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/formtastic_changes.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-15 08:10:33 -0400
Served asset /formtastic_changes.css - 304 Not Modified (3ms)
[2012-07-15 08:10:33] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/formtastic.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-15 08:10:33 -0400
Served asset /formtastic.css - 304 Not Modified (5ms)
[2012-07-15 08:10:33] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/nested_form.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-15 08:10:33 -0400
Served asset /nested_form.js - 304 Not Modified (3ms)
[2012-07-15 08:10:33] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-15 08:10:33 -0400
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (9ms)
[2012-07-15 08:10:33] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/scaffold.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-15 08:10:33 -0400
Served asset /scaffold.css - 304 Not Modified (3ms)
[2012-07-15 08:10:33] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

I suspect there's something I'm accidentally calling somewhere, or something...but I have no idea.

Comment: There is no need to have `nested_form.js` in `app/assets/javascripts`. You have already included `jquery_nested_form` in `application.js`. Could you please try to remove `app/assets/javascripts/nested_form.js` file?

Comment: Yes, I did that...the uncaught type error is gone, but now I'm getting a 404 on assets/nested_form.js .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUCCESS!

I figured it out...but I still don't quite understand why these answers are the right answers. Thank you all for your help and suggestions. It turned out that there were three things I had to do.

1) @lest was correct that I needed to take nested_form.js out of my assets/javascripts folder.
2) I had to switch from calling javascript_include_tag :defaults to javascript_include_tag 'application'.
3) I had to reorder my tree in application.js as follows (I previously had jquery and jquery_ujs swapped, at the recommendation of something I read elsewhere on stackoverflow):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: 2) you'll see javascript_include_tag 'application' if you generate a new rails app. 3) jquery_ujs depends on jquery so it needs to be required after it, you can generate a new rails app and check how it's done there

Answer (score 0):

Prototype ships with Rails, even if you're not using it directly. I've ran into some conflicts before like this. You may try the suggestion mentioned on [another Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528670/how-to-get-jquery-to-work-with-prototype), which is to say:

> use jQuery.noConflict(); and after this all calls to jquery should be
>   done only using the jQuery() instead of $()

(By the way, it's not clear to me if this error is happening in code you've written or in 3rd party code. Even if it's in 3rd party code, you could try modifying it to use the jQuery() in the part that errors only and see if that gets you past the conflict.)_

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. The error is in response to the first line of nested_form.js which is part of the nested_form gem by Ryan Bates. I tried adding jQuery.noConflict(); at the top of that file, but it didn't help...also tried putting it in the head of my layout file, which also didn't help. And I thought that Rails 3.2 shipped with jQuery, not Prototype. Since I can't find anyone else on the internet having this problem, I'm guessing it is mostly that I know nearly nothing about javascript.